# Can I avoid sending props to child and back?

Tags: reactjs, use-state, react-props

I have an array of objects:

```
const arrayOfObjects = [
    { name: 'Sushi', price: 10 },
    { name: 'Pizza',price: 5 }
  ];
```

I'm mapping trough them to generate child Components.

```
const List = arrayOfObjects.map(item => (
    <Child name={item.name} price={item.price} propFunc={parentFunc}></Child>
  ));
```

In a function in the parent component I need values from the array as well as an input value from the child component.

```
const parentFunc = (arg1, arg2) => {
    setItems(prev => {
      return [...prev, { meal: arg1, amount: arg2 }];
    });
  };
```

In the Child component I'm not using the props, just sending them back:

```
const Child = props => {
  const childFunc = event => {
    const var1 = event.target.value;
    const var2 = props.name;
    const var3 = props.price;

    props.propFunc(var1, var2, var3);
  };
};
```

This seems redundant. Can I access the values from the array without sending them back and forth?

I'm looking for a solution that doesn't use other React Hooks and doesn't alter the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by creating a function for each child, with those functions knowing the corresponding item:

```
const list = arrayOfObjects.map(item => (
  <Child propFunc={(event) => parentFunc(event, item.name, item.price))} />
));

// ...

const Child = props => {
  const childFunc = event => {
    props.propFunc(event.target.value);
  };
};
```